Quadtree adaptive binning algorithm with minimum bin contents
I have a two-dimensional histogram and I would like to re-bin it such that all the bins either have zero entries or a minimum number n. The Quad Tree approach similar to what is used in this package, would be acceptable but there is not much documentation there and I would like to do something slightly different than the standard case. If I understand the standard case correctly you specify the maximum number of "levels" by the input N to the function qthist and then specify maximum number of allowed bins with the input thresh. On my data, using this execution:
num, xmin_bin, xmax_bin, ymin_bin, ymax_bin = qthist(pt,qi, N=5,thresh=20,rng=[[1,40],[1,14]])

The algorithm produces:

There are many bins with a small number of points. I want to have >=, say 10 or 20 points in every bin (large bin size is allowed).
Is there a code package that is designed to accomplish this? If not, what is the best way to accomplish this? I am open to other more exotic partitioning like Voronoi but would rather stay rectangular if possible.
I tried to think of whether my desired algorithm is well-posed. I guess it should be as long as the original data has more than n entries. Although, I realize that it might not work as I envision because if early-on in the division process some bin has >0 but <n points, it effectively prevents the algorithm from digging down more finely into 3/4 of that box.
